# show percentage but without percentage sigh in chart

Tags: excel, macos

I have this bar chart that displays percentages (below).

[image]

Is it possible to adjust the format to show percentage but without the percentage sign? i.e as below?

[image]

I know I can change the source (which is done in the below picture). But I am looking for a solution where I can change the format of the bars instead, the format of a simple bar chart displaying % is `0%;;;`, I have tried changing that to `0;;;`, `0;;;*100` etc but I cannot manage to get the second graph. This is on excel for mac!

Comment: Right click on the numbers and select `Format Data Labels` and from there you can change the format the same way as change any other cell.

Comment: Do as TIm Wilkinson wrote, and create custom number format like this:http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/01/31/custom-number-formats-multiply-divide-by-any-power-of-10/

Comment: That is exactly what I have tried, but the custom format never ends up right.

Comment: It asks for "Ctrl+J" in that page @bzimor but that is not the same in mac as windows

Comment: well... if it's not solution, just add intermediate column with `*100` and use this column to express in bar chart

Comment: well, if i change the format to remove % i will get a decimal, 0.25 etc, wont work to multiply this with 100 either

Answer (score 0):

Add some steps:

In the cell below or beside your data series  put a formula in that converts % into a whole number  (25% x 100 = 25)

Right click on the numbers and select Format Data Labels and from there you can change the format the same way as change any other cell. – Tim Wilkinson

Once in the data labels formatting , check the option to get the value from a cell.  Select the cells below the data series (25).

Comment: I cannot change the source sorry, must change directly in graph.